# TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from contract to address requested

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I am unable to use the 'this' Keyword in below code.

```
    function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
    require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
    require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= _numberOfTokens);(issue is here)
    require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));
```

giving below error.

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid 
  implicit conversion from contract DappTokenSale to address requested.
    require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= _numberOfTokens);
```

Comment: Replying to @goodvibration Thanks for the tip! The comment says implicit conversion from contract DappTokenSale to address. So just use an explicit conversion instead - change this to address(this). Fully written out explicit conversion would be in your contract: require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The comment says `implicit conversion from contract DappTokenSale to address`.

So just use an explicit conversion instead - change `this` to `address(this)`.

Comment: Oh my bad its so silly question. Thanks @goodvibration for that.